# Как реализовать парсер URL ссылок Яндекс поиска? (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android, url, webview

Пробовал разные новые методы на stackoverflow и не нашел рабочий.
Метод которому я задаю поисковую ссылку и получаю ссылки выдаваемые Яндексом.
Пример: 
1) Пишем в поиск: VK

```
https://yandex.ru/search/?text=vk
```

2) Получаем ссылки:

```
https://vk.com/
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ВКонтакте
https://twitter.com/vkontakte
```

и т.п.
Можно задавать кол-во в цикле или 
до конца первой страницы Яндекса (page, &p=1)
Спасибо за прочтение.

Comment: Прочитал, спасибо, что задали еще один не понятный никому вопрос.

Comment: @dmtr, мне нужно получить ссылки на страницы которые выдает поисковик Яндекс.

Comment: @dmtr я дополнил вопрос :)

Comment: У Яндекса есть API для таких вещей.